Was the financial crash of 2008 caused by top graduates of the American Ivy Leagues working at wall street banks?
From this article by Lisandro 'Leloy' Claudio, a Chair of the Center for Southeast Asia Studies at UC Berkeley:

a country can become a sad place if its most brilliant minds prioritize profit. In the 1990s and 2000s, most of the top graduates of the American Ivy League went to big Wall Street banks, and it was these geniuses who caused the financial crash of 2008. The world would have been better off if they had done something else.

Was the financial crash of 2008 caused by top graduates of the American Ivy Leagues working at Wall Street banks?

Deleted pseudo-answers in comments. Please use the answer box.

@Oddthinking wow the guy is in UC Berkeley. thanks for the info.

This question is based on a fallacy: Fallacy of the single cause:

The fallacy of the single cause, also known as causal oversimplification, is a fallacy of questionable cause that occurs when it is assumed that there is a single, simple cause of an outcome when in reality it may have been caused by a number of only jointly sufficient causes.

It is not a reasonable position to argue that there is a single cause of a phenomena as complex as the Global Economic Crisis (GEC).
The Wikipedia page on the GEC just gives an overview of the events, and can't be held up as a reliable source, but it suffices here to illustrate that there were multiple factors. It points to:

Predatory lending in the form of subprime mortgages targeting low-income homebuyers


excessive risk-taking by global financial institutions,


continuous buildup of toxic assets within banks


the bursting of the United States housing bubble


in 1999, parts of the Glass-Steagall legislation, which had been adopted in 1933, were repealed, permitting financial institutions to commingle their commercial (risk-averse) and proprietary trading (risk-taking) operations.


the rapid development in predatory financial products which targeted low-income, low-information homebuyers who largely belonged to racial minorities.


This market development went unattended by regulators

Every single one of these items were a necessary condition for the GEC to be such a big crisis. Some, but not all, of them were the responsibility of Wall Street banks.
But this isn't an exclusive list of causes, and we can brainstorm many more that weren't the responsibility of Wall Street banks, ad absurdum: the free market, greed, the precedents of Hammurabi on legal systems, legally permitting usury.
As Douglas Adams put it:

Many were increasingly of the opinion that they’d all made a big mistake in coming down from the trees in the first place.

So, it isn't necessary to trust the Wikipedia article's point of view to acknowledge that there are many different factors involved.
I believe the reason this question has been downvoted and left unanswered is because the core idea - that there was a single cause of the Global Economic Crisis, and it can be blamed on a very particular class of employees - is clearly an oversimplification, and probably intended as rhetoric rather than an empirical fact.

Who said anything about Wikipedia?

@BCLC: Err... I did. I used Wikipedia as a source, which is suboptimal, and then justified why it didn't matter as it wasn't essential for the argument, it was just illustrative.

Ok I'm gonna be explicit here to be clear at the cost of sounding, or even actually being, arrogant or ignorant. When I 1st read this like I was just about to start grad school in mathematical finance/quantitative finance. No offense or anything, but I actually kinda figured that the prof is not only wrong about this but has no idea what e is talking about. Does the quote make substantial sense?

@BCLC: I am happy for you to be explicit for clarity, but I still didn't understand (What's grad school got to do with it?) My answer argues that the claim is based on a fallacy, and so it doesn't hold. The original argument doesn't make sense.
